# Where is intercom status of an extension stored in asterisk/freepbx?

Tags: php, asterisk

I want to add a checkbox in the application/extensions section(in freepbx admin panel) which when checked enables intercom mode and when unchecked disables intercom mode. I want to do the same thing in another page too.I already did this much but I can't find where intercom mode value( or auto answer value) is stored/ how is it stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out finally. It s in the asterisk's SQLite Database. The code for storing/reading this is located in /var/www/html/admin/modules/core/functions.inc.php. This file includes a lot more stuffs and core functions.

I wrote two functions for setting and getting the intercom status

```
<?php

function setIntercomStatus($extension,$status)
{
    global $db;
    global $amp_conf;
    global $astman;



    if($extension!='')
    {

        if($astman)
        {

        $result = $astman->database_put("AMPUSER",$extension."/answermode","\""
            . (isset($status) ? $status : '')
            . "\"");

        }
        else 
            { 
                die("Error connecting to database");
            }

    }
}
function getIntercomStatus($extension)
{
    global $db;
    global $amp_conf;
    global $astman;

    if($extension != '' and $astman)
    {


          $answermode=$astman->database_get("AMPUSER",$extension."/answermode");

          if($answermode)
          {
            return (trim($answermode) == '') ? 'disabled' : $answermode;;
          }
          else {
              return "Extension Not Found";  
          }


    }


}

?>
```

$status in set function may be 'intercom' or 'disabled'

$astman is an instance of AGI_AsteriskManager in package phpAGI (located at /var/www/html/admin/libraries/php-asmanager.php). The intercom status for an extension is stored in database "AMPUSER" / extension_number / answermode.

Answer (score 1):

I think nice page to start with is http://www.freepbx.org/development

Also easy way to spot dialplan is do following:

```
asterisk -r
core set verbose 10

enable intercom, call

disable intercom, call
```

Most of values are in db or asterisk database.